# This regex not working for <b>

Tags: regex

```
</?(?i:script|div|table|frameset|b|frame|iframe|style)(.|\n)*?>
```

I'm trying to filter certain HTML elements using this regex expression.  I also want to filter "b" and "/b" as well but it doesn't seem to work for those.

Thank you.

Comment: This may or may not apply here, but you should give this a read:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Do you use a specific programming language?

Comment: Works for me, using Perl.  You may want to try your regex in a test script, to see whether the problem is your regex or some other part of your code.

Comment: Also -- use an HTML parser, if possible.  Doing this with regexes is very hard (impossible?) to get right.  For example, I could sneak onto your page and write this:  `<<script>script>`.  See also Brad's link, which is both amusing and good advice.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to instead of *removing* some specific tags, to *allow* some specific tags, and remove all other. That is, have a default-forbid policy.

Comment: Can you tell me what that allow would look like?  TY for your reply.

Comment: Well, instead of removing the tags that match, remove all other tags. Btw, is this question intended for a specific programming language? (I could probably help you further if it's Java.)

Comment: `(.|\n)` matches everything, including newlines.  `[.\n]` matches only periods and newlines.  I think the first was intended.